# R package warning: Files in the 'vignettes' directory newer than all files in 'inst/doc'

Tags: r, pdf, sweave, vignette

In an R package I have two legacy Sweave vignettes as `.Rnw` files.  When I check the package locally (in R Studio: Build -> Check), there are no errors, or warnings, and the same thing goes when my package is checked on R-Forge using R version 3.3.1 Patched (2016-10-17 r71531).

However, when I submit the package to Win-builder (via `devtools::build_win()`) for checking under R devel (unstable) (2016-10-16 r71524)), I get the following warnings that I am unable to resolve:

```
Files in the 'vignettes' directory newer than all files in 'inst/doc':
  'fig/plot-Ortho-fm1.pdf', 'fig/plot-Ortho-fm3.pdf',
    'fig/plot-grades-can-class.pdf', 'fig/plot-grades-can-gpa.pdf',
    'fig/plot-grades-can-sex.pdf', 'fig/plot-grades-pairs.pdf',
    'fig/plot-hern-can-age.pdf', 'fig/plot-hern-can-build.pdf',
    'fig/plot-hern-can-cardiac.pdf', 'fig/plot-hern-can-pstat.pdf',
    'fig/plot-hern-pairs.pdf', 'fig/plot-jury-can1.pdf',
    ...
```

My package directory structure includes the vignettes in `vignettes/` and the the result of `devtools::build_vignettes()` in `inst/doc/`, as follows:

```
...
man/
inst/
   doc/HE-examples.{pdf,R,Rnw}
   doc/repeated.{pdf,R,Rnw}
R/
vignettes/HE-examples.Rnw
         /repeated.Rnw
         /fig/   # all generated fig files
```

The reason that I include the generated `.pdf` files in `inst/doc/` is that otherwise I get a warning that the `.pdf` files need to be compressed with `qpdf`, and the only way I can actually do this is to open them in Acrobat Pro and re-save as compressed PDF.

I've tried adding `inst/doc` to `.Rbuildignore`, but that generates an error.  I also tried adding `inst/doc/*.pdf` to `.Rbuildignore` but that has no effect.

The warning is preventing me from submitting an update to CRAN.  I don't understand why newer files in `vignettes/` should be a problem, but how can I fix the warning?

Comment: Just a command: you can use the command `tools::compactPDF()` to reduce your vignettes.

Comment: I've tried this, but for some reason, it has no effect on the PDF files, even though I have `qpdf` and `gs` installed.

Comment: Newer files in `vignettes/` are a problem because the ones in `inst/doc` are probably from some previous version of the vignette.  You may have done some work on the vignette and it won't be shown to users.

Answer (score 5):

I'm posting an answer in case anyone else runs into this problem.

This problem is mentioned in this [devtools issue #1348](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/1348). The solution there was simply to delete all the vignette files under `inst/doc`.  In my case, one vignette PDF file required manual compression to avoid the complaint about `qpdf`.

After deleting all files under `inst/doc/`, I re-copied the compressed PDF file, so it was now newer than the files under `vignettes/`

Both problems solved, and the CRAN daemon is happy.